# Reading files in a directory and saving each dynamically

Tags: python, spacy

```
text_open = open("inputfiles/(22).txt", "r")
text = text_open.read()

doc = nlp(text)
db.add(doc)
db.to_disk("./outputfiles/22.spacy")
```

I am trying to loop over each of the 500+ documents in the inputfiles folder and output them through db.to_disk. Instead of changing the hard coded numbers every-time, how would I dynamically rename each new output file to match the input file?

If I were to open the directory with glob/os, how do I then add this to the output directory without overwriting every single file with the hardcoded '22' or creating new 22(1).spacy, 22(2).spacy etc files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.6+, then use `f-string`s.

```py
for i in range(1, 501):
    text_open = open(f"inputfiles/({i}).txt", "r")
    text = text_open.read()

    doc = nlp(text)
    db.add(doc)
    db.to_disk(f"./outputfiles/{i}.spacy")
```

Would it help?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I touched a bit on f-strings in Flask but didn't know they work in base python too. I tried the above code and it only outputs the penultimate file in the range (e.g. in range(1, 501) it would be 500, and (1,100) it would output 99. How come?

Comment: @goonhoon you can look it up in the document of Python: <https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#range>

Comment: Thanks :) I figured it out. Some parts of the code were outside of the loop and so it only registered the last object in the range.